# Use the string name of an object to modify its properties in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I want to use the String value of a varible in order to access a control in the site.master. This string will be the name of the control.

The name of the object is **login**, and i want to modify its visible property to ***false***. The thing is that i have the name in a string.

```
   Dim name As String = "Login" ' this string comes from the database
   name.Visible = True
```

I am using asp.net with vb.net. the object that i want to edit its properties is the following in the site master:

```
<a id="Login" runat="server" href="Login.aspx"><img id="Img1" alt="Back to home page" runat="server" src="DynamicData/Content/Images/back.gif" />Login</a>
```

Thank you Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE>
<script runat="server">
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
'
Dim name As String = "Login" ' this string comes from the database
Dim item As Object
'
For Each item In Me.Controls
  If item.id = name Then
    item.visible = False
    Exit For
  End If
Next
End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="Login" runat="server" href="default.aspx"><img id="Img1" alt="Back to home page" runat="server" src="DynamicData/Content/Images/back.gif" />Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

To check it works properly, simply REMark out the line which sets the visibility to false.

Comment: Thank you this solve my problem. In fact, in the web.master i used the ID to differentiate every object that i want to hide. Therefor i stored those names in a database and every time that a user enter the page, the page query the database to "know" what screens have to be shown.